# Chrome icons and tabs size

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Seems like out of nowhere my Chrome icons and tabs got bigger, I didn't do anything for it to happen.

I'm running Version 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit) and Win10 which just recently has made some upgrades. I've already tried most of the tricks on the subjects as when I first got this laptop I had the opposite problem (icons too small) then I got used to it.

Comment: Perhaps try right clicking on your desktop > `Display settings` and rolling the scale back down to a suitable size. The "suitable" size will be indicated once you see "Recommended" next to the % value, (click here for image)[http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/general-support/35678d1441384212t-need-get-new-dpi-value-registry-windows-10-a-arqd0fl.png]

Comment: This scales down the size of everything, I need to scale down the size of Chrome's incons and tabs.

Comment: I'm aware of what it does, I just wondered that this may have been the root cause since you upgraded to Windows 10.

Comment: I was already running Win10 with previous settings (Chrome small icons and all the rest normal size).

Comment: Google Chrome recently updated appearance on my browser to, i changed that by going to chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md and set the flag to Non-material. But not sure if it's the same problem that you have... Check [these](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/KYdoZG_pVpk) two answers marked as best and tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a new design, introduced in the latest version of Chrome.

To revert to the old design, go to chrome://flags and set "Material Design in the browser's top chrome" to "Non-material". For me, at least, this puts the tabs back to their previous size.